# how to delete specific characters without deleting a file using sed

Tags: bash, sed

So I have a file

```
a b b c
a b c d
a b c d e f
```

How would I remove the character "b" without deleting anything else using sed.

Comment: An easy way would use `tr -d b < file.txt > b-less-file.txt`, but that cheats because it doesn't use `sed`.  Some versions of `sed` support a `-i` option to overwrite the original file.  If you want the same code to work with both the Mac OS X (BSD) and Linux (GNU) versions of `sed`, use `-i.bak` (no space).  If you want no backup file, you have to treat them differently: BSD requires `-i ''` (two arguments, the second one empty), and GNU requires just `-i` (one argument).

Comment: @John1024 I've tried using tr -d <file.txt but that wouldn't write it to the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me: `sed 's/b//g' file.ext`

Answer (score 1):

Using sed it could be something like this:

```
sed 's|[b]||g'
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Why use a character class when you could simply use `s|b||` (or, more conventionally, `s/b//`)?  It'll work, and it extends nicely if you need to remove `b` and `m` and `z`, but …

Answer (score 1):

`awk` : gsub function to replace every `b` from all the records.

```
awk '{gsub(/b/," ")}1' fil
a     c
a   c d
a   c d e f
```

`sed` : Sed solution , replace `b` with nothing `(//)` or a space`(/ /)`.

```
sed 's/b//g' fil
a   c
a  c d
a  c d e f
```

`tr` : Replace `b` with blank space , so alignment is not hampered.

```
tr  'b' ' ' <fil
a     c
a   c d
a   c d e f
```

`tr` : Delete `b` from the file, this may impact file alignment.

```
 tr -d 'b' <fil
a   c
a  c d
a  c d e f
```